# Meteor and xolvio:cucumber

Tags: meteor, cucumber, webdriver-io

Today I decided to give testing in Meteor another try. I decided to try out xolvio:cucumber and the first test I decided to create simply visited a non-existent page and checked for the "Page not found" text. It worked well so decided to duplicate this test and do basically the same thing for "/login". The second test is so similar to the first I thought it would would be easy - but a whole 7 hours later I'm still trying to get the test to pass.

Here is a gist of my steps and features.

https://gist.github.com/ciwolsey/5f9addcfdd240638e7e1

The problem area is line 30 of the steps:

waitForVisible('#at-forgotPwd', 10000)

It times out no matter what I put in the selector. I've various types of selectors including xPath and still it times out as if the element never becomes visible.

It might be useful to know that the "/login" route is provided by the "useraccounts:core" package.

Comment: not a solution to your problem, but i've been using the velocity/robotframework bundle and found it to be totally awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to use waitForExists and not waitForVisible since the element is likely being added/removed from the DOM.